# Windows Phone Bind Listbox With a Listbbx

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I have a class with a list of images in it.

```
    public class RSSClass
{
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Summary { get; set; }
public string PubDate { get; set; }
public List<ImageData> ImagePath { get; set; }

public class ImageData
{
    public Uri ImageLocation
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
}
```

Hers the XAML

```
           <ListBox Name="lstRSS">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel.Resources>
                            </StackPanel.Resources>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"> </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PubDate}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Summary}"></TextBlock>
                            <ListBox x:Name="ImageListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagePath}">
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image x:Name="image1" Source="{Binding}" MaxHeight="80" MaxWidth="120" Margin="0"></Image>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

The inner list box, ImageListBox, binds and shows the string value of the Uri. Im just not sure what to bind the image in the inner list box, image1, to?

Any help much appreciated.

Regards
Ross

Comment: Have you tried Source="{Binding ImageLocation}" ?

Comment: Tried that mate, no luck, thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Have you tried using a string as the ImageLocation rather than a Uri?

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, that didnt work either Im afraid. The area where the list box should show up diplays "System.Windows.DataTemplate". So I figure the issue is that Im not binding correctly :(

Comment: Did you try the specific ImageLocation binding as well as the type being string rather than Uri?

Comment: Hi Paul, yes tried both of those :(

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>` around your `<DataTemplate>`. This confuses ListBox, so it thinks it is actualy an item, not a template.

Comment: Thats for the suggestion Euphoric. When I add the suggested ItemTemplate I get some kind of binding, the ListBox contains a number of "RSSClass+ImageData" Strings. When I remove it nothing is rendered. So it looks like the listbox is binding to the object, just not the Image inside.

Comment: Did you add it correctly? What you describe happens when there is no DataTemplate specified, thus it binds to ToString of object.

Answer (score 0):

Once you implement @Euphoric's resolution, bind the image1's source to ImageLocation. Example:

```
<Image x:Name="image1" Source="{Binding ImageLocation}" MaxHeight="80" MaxWidth="120" Margin="0"></Image>
```